# Mysterious:Selecting a large Xml in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, varcharmax

I am having a column in my table which stores XML data as a varchar(MAX).For example one of my value has around 1 LAC characters.While selecting it from the Table, i end up getting only 43679 characters for all samples.

What is the reason behind this mystery?Please,if there is any way to retrieve the complete data,help.

Comment: Without some samples, it is difficult to tell where the problem could be.  Is the transport web, or is it standard connection.  Is it the actual data being truncated due to newline or invalid chars.

Answer (score 4):

Try using settings of sql server management studio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After changing this also results the same?

Answer (score 2):

try to select with a cast:

```
select top 1 cast(ColumnName as xml) from Table
```

Comment: really help me to get large xml value from select query, Thanks

Comment: Yup, it is a good approach.